# list comprehension - how to write previous number?

Tags: python

How to select the previous number in list comprehension that starts from the second one?

The formula is `[w(j-1)* 5 +w for t in y]`?

`w(j-1)` is the first number in list.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve. Therefore, my own interpretation of the problem. Assume you have a list of numbers:

```
my_list = range(1, 10)
```

Now we want to iterate over this list starting from the second entry and also access the previous entry:

```
new_list = [my_list[i - 1]*5 + my_list[i] for i, n in enumerate(my_list) if i > 0]
print(new_list)
```

This way you can get access to a list element and its predecessor.

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, thank you.  But when I multiply this list with decimal numbers, I received an error "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

Comment: In Python, you cannot multiply lists with numbers. Instead, `[1,2, 3]*2` results in a doubled list `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`. If you want vector arithmetics, you need the package `numpy`. You can multiply numpy-arrays with numbers.

Comment: do you want to multiply each list element by decimal number?